# How can I get the color in the middle of a face using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, vertex-colors

Say I have a mesh and I have colored the vertices using vertex paint, how can I then get the average of the colors or rather the ***color in the middle of the face*** or the color under the normal *(shown below)* using blender python?

[image]

Comment: I'm sort of guessing here but I think that point can be obtained using some barycentric coordinates function.

Comment: The "middle" of the face might be vague. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Points.2C_lines.2C_and_circles_associated_with_a_triangle) for the different definitions of midpoints. I think you refer to the median / centroid according to the site linked.

Comment: Btw there exists a function to deal with barycentric coordinates -> [mathutils.geometry.barycentric_transform](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_8/mathutils.geometry.html#mathutils.geometry.barycentric_transform) though this is not needed for the median

Answer (score 8):

In the middle of a face is an average color of all the vertices. For triangle this means:

Col_RGB = ((R<sub>1</sub>+R<sub>2</sub>+R<sub>3</sub>)/3, (G<sub>1</sub>+G<sub>2</sub>+G<sub>3</sub>)/3, (B<sub>1</sub>+B<sub>2</sub>+B<sub>3</sub>)/3)

Where each vert has color in form of (R<sub>n</sub>, G<sub>n</sub>, B<sub>n</sub>) for n in (1..3).

Comment: It's cheaper to add all vertex vectors and divide once by the number of vertices.